# Webview content dosn't match its width to parent after changing orientation from landscape to portrait

Tags: android, android-layout, webview

One fragment in my app is displaying articles from my website in webview. To allow changing orientation I placed `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in my activity in manifest.
Everything is working properly except webview displaying in that fragment. When I change the screen orientation from landscape to portrait webview looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rU7JZ.png). Only advertisement matches width to parent, [check it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWgIT.png).

The interesting thing is, that this thing happens only when I load the article in landscape, and then change to portrait.
When I load article in portrait, then change it to landscape, and second time to portrait webview content matches its width to the screen properly. Please, check it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23ZQY.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f13mr.png).

The configuration of webview in my fragment:

```
contentWebView = view.findViewById(R.id.contentWebView);
    contentWebView.setWebChromeClient(new FullScreenInWebviewClient(contentRelativeLayout,
            contentWebView, mainActivity.getSupportActionBar()));
    contentWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);

            if(url != null && (url.startsWith("http://") || url.startsWith("https://"))){

                view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
                return true;

            } else{
                return false;
            }

        }


    });

    contentWebView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    WebSettings webSettings = contentWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.TEXT_AUTOSIZING);
    webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```

My relative layout file:

```
<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/contentWebView"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/contentProgressBar"
    android:background="@xml/progress"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    />
```

How can I solve this problem? Is advertisement causing this fault? Thanks for any help!

**Edit:**
This problem was caused by ads. JavaScript code which was displaying them did that. 
I deleted those ads from webview and implemented ads in my app with Google adMob. Now changing orientation works perfectly without any problems.

Comment: Would you post the layout file as well please?

Comment: Now You can see it.

Comment: Try to put all the setting before loading data into it, may this causing the issues.

Comment: I do that in this order all the time.